# Turn off level shifter

Tags: power-supply, esp32, led-strip, level-shifting

I'm designing an LED controller with ESP for SK6812 and there are many of them connected so I need an extra power supply. The ESP uses 3.3 V but the LED's 5 V so I need a level shifter. There is not the problem. But I want as protection feature that the LED's only get power by the power supply to safe the USB from high current flow. The ESP should normally also get powered by the power supply. I think that should fix a diode from the 5 V of power supply to the 5 V of USB. The USB is just to upload code. So if the power supply is off and I uploaded code the level shifter should not let any signal through, to not damage the unpowered LEDs. There comes the problem for me if I use the often used schematic like below.
[image: BSS138 Schematic]
The LV1 connected to ESP IO-pin, the HV1 connected to LED's input, the LV to 3.3V and the HV to the 5 V of the power supply. If the power supply is off the level shifter let the 3.3 V through to the LED's input. And I don't want that.

Can anyone tell me how to improve my schematic or tell me an other solution?

Comment: My first question is, does that level shifter even work, have you tried it? Also if you are programming the ESP, the pin will not be an output, correct?

Comment: If I understand you correctly (and I'm not confident I do), you want to use the MOSFET as switch ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2YnF.png)), not as a level shifter. (image source: https://www.microtype.io/selecting-a-mosfet-a-pragmatic-approach/)

Comment: @Justme The level shifter work you can even buy an board from e.g. sparkfun (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009). Yes while programming the pin is no output but if ready programmed and the programm runs without the power supply there shouldn't be output some thing.

Comment: @Velvel may it will work with the MOSFET as switch but this would invert the output, or isn't that correct? And can I drive the MOSFET with 5V at Drain and 3.3V at Gate?

Comment: @4Source Most questions here about such a FET level shifter is that why it does not work with high speed data over long wires like for addressable RGB leds. I suggest using a logic IC which allows input while being unpowered.

Comment: @Justme Ok didn't tried it with the long wire, may would't work with that. Can you recommend any IC?

Comment: _"but this would invert the output, or isn't that correct?"_ Yes. If you're in control of the firmware, you can account for that. Otherwise you can add a second stage.

Comment: _"And can I drive the MOSFET with 5V at Drain and 3.3V at Gate?"_ Yes, as long as it meets the specs of the MOSFET. The [2N2007](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00005134.pdf) is a N-channel MOSFET I'll commonly pick to drive a low-current status LED.

Comment: I think I found an suitable IC the 74LVC1T45 have fast switching times and also supports one power supply to turn off to isolate the signal. If I understand the [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74LVC1T45.pdf) correctly.

Comment: @4Source Yes, 74LVC1T45 provides such an isolation. I used them for FT2232H-based JTAG/SPI flashing adapter with variable Vtarget and independent adapter/target board powering.
You can also use 2-channel 74LVC2T45 (common OE and DIR) and even faster 74AVC1T45